# Reading/writing undefined unicode characters to a file

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

#### Short version:

Writing a string containing chars between values 55296 and 57343 (inclusive) to a file results in those characters being replaced with question marks ('?'), meaning that the resulting file cannot be read back to the original string.

How can this problem be avoided/circumvented?

#### Long version:

I have an array of integers between 0 and 65535 (inclusive) which I am attempting to write to a file so that I can retrieve that array at a later time. An example array below:

```
int[] integerArray = new int[] {2404,44698,55597,17382,35641,10988};
```

Understanding that unicode has exactly 65536 characters, and that Java's char data also has 65536 values, I decided to do this by casting each of these integers to a character, adding them to a string, and then writing that string to a file like so:

```
private static void writeUnicodeToFile(int[] array, String path) {
    String unicode = "";
    for(int integer : array) unicode += (char) integer;
    try { Files.write(Path.of(path), unicode.getBytes());
    } catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

This is effective most of the time, however in the case of the example array, casting the value 55597 returns the question mark ('?') character, so that when I attempt to retrieve the values like so:

```
private static int[] getUnicodeFromFile(String path) {
    String unicode = "";
    try { unicode = Files.readString(Path.of(path));
    } catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    int[] integerArray = new int[unicode.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < unicode.length(); i++) integerArray[i] = (int) unicode.charAt(i);
    return integerArray;
}
```

The returned array contains 63 (the unicode id of the question mark) at index 2 instead of 55597.

Searching the value 55597 in a unicode character table revealed that it is not a valid character, and further experimentation revealed that there are 2049 characters in unicode which will be written to a file as a question mark (including the question mark itself). All other characters can be written and read just fine.

However, this means that it is not possible to decode the file back into the integer array, as one character can be interpreted to mean 2048 others.

So how can I distinguish all of these characters from each other such that I can read/write them to and from a file without them interfering with one another?

Alternatively, could I somehow use a different character set to avoid this problem entirely? I'm flexible to converting each integer to two values from 0 to 255 and using some other text file encoding settings for instance.

#### Other possibly-relevant information:

I am using the Eclipse IDE, and have set my workspace's text file encoding to UTF-8 (which I understand to be equivalent to unicode).

Comment: Regarding _"...unicode has exactly 65536 characters..."_, that was never true. About 25 years ago Unicode had a theoretical maximum character set size of 65,536, but now there is no practical limit. See [How many Unicode characters are there?](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/HowMany.html)  That's not directly relevant to your question, but still worth clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, OP here:

I have a solution which works, but it's not optimal, so I'll still appreciate any other solutions people have.

Instead of attempting to write unicode to the file directly, I turned each integer into two bytes using the code below:

```
//Get bytes from the data
private static byte[] decombineData(int[] data) {
    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[data.length*2]; // Create an array of bytes to write to
    //Write to each byte using the data in the string
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        byte[] twoBytes = decombineBytes((int)data[i]); // Decombine the bytes of a character
        dataBytes[i*2] = twoBytes[0];
        dataBytes[i*2+1] = twoBytes[1];
    }
    return dataBytes; // Return the array of bytes
}

//Take a value from 0 to 65536 inclusively and return two bytes that would combine to make that value
private static byte[] decombineBytes(int combinedValue) {
    return new byte[] {(byte)(combinedValue/256-128), (byte)(combinedValue%256-128)};
}
```

Calling decombineData on the array of integers will broduce an array of bytes. Here's the method to apply it in reverse:

```
// Turn an array of compressed bytes into a set of integers
private static int[] combineData(byte[] bytes) {
    int[] integers = new int[(bytes.length+1)/2]; // Initialise the return string
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i+=2) { // Create the return string from the compressed bytes
        if (i+1 != bytes.length) { integers[i] = combineBytes(bytes[i],bytes[i+1]); } // Compress two bytes if enough characters exist
        else { integers[i] = (combineBytes(bytes[i],(byte)0)); } // Otherwise only compress one byte
    }
    return integers;
}

//Combine two bytes into a single integer from 0 to 65536 inclusively
private static int combineBytes(byte byteOne, byte byteTwo) {
    return (byteOne*256)+byteTwo+32896;
}
```

To write to the file, you can use the same code as before, but using the bytes directly instead of .getBytes():

```
private static void writeBytesToFile(byte[] bytes, String path) {
    try { Files.write(Path.of(path), bytes);
    } catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

And a similar method for reading:

```
public static byte[] readBytesFromFile(String path) {
    try { return Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(path));
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(1); }
    return null;
}
```